# codeigniter url case sensitive issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have written a controller with name `CMS` (capital letter). When I call the link http://localhost/CI/testing/admin/cms/insert, It has no problem. Its working fine in localhost.

After uploading that page to server and when I execute the statement, http://dev.test.in/testing/admin/cms/insert, it doesn't display the page. But when I change the url to http://dev.test.in/testing/admin/CMS/insert, its in a working condition.

In order to solve this either I will have to change the controller name to cms(small letter) or change all the anchor url to CMS. Is there any other solution to solve this. Like writing htaccess file?

Answer (score 3):

The problem exist coz file name differs on Linux and Windows
MyFile & myfile can not exist in a same path in Windows, but can on a Linux

Comment: i think so, but sorry i dont have knowledge on rewrite, but if you have few url then you can rename the files