# CodeIgniter Controller Case-Sensitive

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing my CI project on a localhost, and I never tried to upload it live. Now, this is the first time that I have uploaded my CI project into a web hosting and the URLs are case-sensitive.

```
www.mywebsite.com/content
```

The above code works on localhost, but it doesn't work on live server. This one works:

```
www.mywebsite.com/Content
```

As you notice, there's a capital C in it.

Should I change all the anchors that leads to the Content controller, or is there a way that when I enter `www.mywebsite.com/content` will be converted to `www.mywebsite.com/Content` ?

Comment: What version of Codeigniter?

Comment: @DFriend 3.0.4 is the version of my CI

Comment: Have look through here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html

Comment: Couple things to check. Do all the controller files have a upper-case first character in the actual file name? (e.g. **C**ontent.php) Is the item `$config['base_url']` set correctly in `/application/config/config.php`?

Comment: Yes, all of the controllers start with a capital letter and the base_url is properly set

Comment: This is strange because it should not make any difference whether the URL is `/Content` or `/content`. My sites do not behave that way - both will go to the expected page.

Comment: In localhost, it is case insensitive. I don't know what happened

Comment: yours is linux hosting ?

Comment: @safinchacko Yes, the server uses linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said you are using CI 3.

Codeigniter change log says

> Changed filenaming convention (class file names now must be Ucfirst
>   and everything else in lowercase). So you controllers and files name
>   should be

- My_controller
  (only M upper case rest lower case)
- Public_controller
- Application_controller
- Foo_controller

CI-2 was better in this case.

[Codeigniter Class and filename case sensitive on Linux (centos)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145215/codeigniter-class-and-filename-case-sensitive-on-linux-centos)

Note 1:

Windows hosting and Linux hosting has difference in file names.(Also
Most of the Live Hosting providers (in server) will not give full freedom as working as localhost. There will be some strict modes and policies implemented in server for security reasons.)

Note 2:

The problem exist coz file name differs on Linux and Windows MyFile & myfile can not exist in a same path in Windows, but can on a Linux
[codeigniter url case sensitive issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962160/codeigniter-url-case-sensitive-issue)

Comment: That was exactly my naming convention. It works on the localhost but not on the live server

Comment: Is `ParentPortal` not allowed? Should it be `Parentportal`?

Answer (score 1):

First alphabet in controller's name and Model's name should be uppercase. My CI version is 3.1.0

Comment: Is `ParentPortal` not allowed? Should it be `Parentportal`?

Comment: both are valid as long as first alphabet is uppercase.

Comment: I guess, I know the problem now. I tried `Parentportal` it works even if I type it in the URL as `parentportal` but if I try `ParentPortal`, it doesn't work. So in conclusion, the solution is: only the first letter of the controller must be capitalized