# How do I use underscores and lowercase letters in URLs in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter, twig, codeigniter-3, php-5.6

I am annoyed with encountering mysterious problem.
My development environment has been created with the following directory structure.

```
document_root
　└ project
　　├ application
　　│├ controllers
　　││└ admin
　　││　├ Users.php
　　││　├ Facility_Categories.php
　　││　└ Facilities.php
　　│└ views
　　│　└ admin
　　│　　├ users
　　│　　│└ index.twig
　　│　　├ facility_categories
　　│　　│└ index.twig
　　│　　└ facilities
　　│　　　└ index.twig
　　└ public
　　　└ index.php
```

In the development environment, these URLs appeared as expected.

```
https://www.example.com/project/admin/users/
 -> load admin/Users.php index function
https://www.example.com/project/admin/facilities/
 -> load admin/Facilities.php index function
https://www.example.com/project/admin/facility_categories/
 -> load admin/Facility_Categories.php index function
```

Recently, when I upload these files to a test environment.
URL were not displayed correctly that contained "underscore".
It looks like controller is not loaded.

```
https://www.example.com/project/admin/users/
 -> load admin/Users.php index function
https://www.example.com/project/admin/facilities/
 -> load admin/Facilities.php index function
https://www.example.com/project/admin/facility_categories/
 -> 404 Page Not Found (display codeigniter show_404 function)
```

By the way, if the URL is capitalized, the controller will load but View will not.
(view is also displayed if view's direcotry name is capitalized.)

```
https://www.example.com/project/admin/Facility_Categories/
 -> 500 Internal Server Error
      (Twig\Error\LoaderError : Unable to find template "admin/Facility_Categories/index.twig")
```

I want to access with lower case URL. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: need to look this closely. Information provided not sufficient.

Comment: can i see how you are loading twig file?

Comment: Ok so from your description it appears that your Facility_Categories.php controller is the issue. So can you at least post that. Also what is your "Development" environment and your "Test" environment. Obviously they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem on my own to read following url

[CodeIgniter Controller Case-Sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409413/codeigniter-controller-case-sensitive)

CodeIgniter3 seemed to have to capitalize only the first letter of the controller name and all lowercase after that. (OK: `Facility_categories.php` NG: `Facility_Categories.php`)

I just changed 2 points.

1. Change Controller File Name From `Facility_Categories.php` To `Facility_categories.php`
2. Change Controller Class Name From `class Facility_Categories` To `class Facility_categories`

Now I can access to url that contain lowercase and underscores

```
https://www.example.com/project/admin/facility_categories/
```